# Node.js + Socket.io: Unable to set ping timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

In my Node.js + Socket.io application, I'm trying to set the ping timeout to 63 seconds (63 seconds of inactivity allowed until the connection between the server and the client(s) is considered closed). Unfortunately, when I run my code below, I get the following error:

```
var io = socket(server);
         ^
TypeError: socket is not a function
```

Below is my code:

```
var express = require("express");
var socket = require("socket.io")(3000, {
    pingTimeout: 63000,
});

var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000);

app.use(express.static("public"));

var io = socket(server);
```

Answer (score 0):

just create and pass an http server

```
var http = require("http"); // Require the 'http' module
var socketIo = require("socket.io");

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app); // Create an HTTP server using 'http' module

var io = socketIo(server);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the starter code provided by the [docs](https://socket.io/get-started/chat#serving-html):

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");

// Added here the ping setting
const io = new Server(server, { pingTimeout: 63000 });

// here you may want to expose the public directory instead of serving the file
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');

    socket.on("disconnect", (reason) => {
        console.log(reason); // "ping timeout"
    });
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```